# waitForElementPresent command NightwatchJS

Tags: html, rendering, nightwatch.js

i want to know whether waitForElementPresent only provides time to visible an element.At the same time does waitForElementPresent give the elements rendering time?  For example

```
       client.waitForElementPresent('body', 300);
```

Then result is

```
          Element <body> was present after 23 milliseconds.
```

23 ms is equal that elements rendering time? Is that time be affected from the parameter(300) or (100)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know the time is affected by the parameter you gave him, so in this case its 300ms.